# cannot set 'independent dual headphones' as default playback device

Tags: windows-7, audio, playback

I sometimes listen music from my phone and sometime from my laptop via headphones.

I figured out that my laptop is not giving a stereo output through headphones.

After a little research I figured out that many HP Laptop users have the similar problem.

So, is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: Easiest way is not to use the headphones that came with your phone. The connector you plug in to your laptop will hàve 3 black bands, you want a pair of headphones with only 2 black bands.

Comment: @mokubai I use headphones...not the one which I got with my phone but I brought them seperatly